# What is mcrypt and Why and Where do we need it?

Tags: mcrypt

I came across mcrypt while installing laravel on my local system. The term mcrypt came across and explored the internet for knowing more about it. Nothing substantial came across. Will someone explain. What is mcrypt ? Why, where and how it is used? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

MCrypt is a replacement for the old crypt() package and crypt(1) command, with extensions. It allows developers to use a wide range of encryption functions, without making drastic changes to their code. It allows users to encrypt files or data streams without having to be cryptographers. Above all, it allows you to have some really neat code on your machine.
for more details about MCrypt -Cryptography Extension in php visit https://www.php.net/mcrypt

Answer (score 1):

Mind that mcrypt was deprecated in PHP 7.1 and removed in PHP 7.2 completely. So everything here should be past tense: "What was mcrypt …?". It is recommended to use OpenSSL or other alternatives instead.